# Is database state from source db brought over the the new db when restoring from backup?

Tags: sql-server, database, database-administration, database-backups

#### Brief background info

We´re moving a database from Windows Server 2012 to 2016 in a critical production environment and are experiencing problems where the database on the new server gets set to `Restricted user` after the restore is done. 
**This is the order things are done:**

1. 2012 db is manually set to restricted user
2. Backup is made from 2012 db
3. 2016 db is restored using backup in step 2
4. 2016 db is unwillingly set to `restricted user`

The reason that we set the 2012 db in `restricted user` in the first place is to force logged in users to a stand-by environment while the 2016 db is being set-up.

The team that is doing this backup and restore claims that the database state is included in the backup as well and that that's the reason the new database get's set into `restricted user` as soon as the restore is done.

The new database being set to `restricted user` is not a huge problem since it's possible to manually change it back to `multi user`, but since this environment is of such critical nature, we don't want to risk having our users on the backup system any longer then necessary

#### So here's the actuall question:

When restoring a database from a backup, is the database state included in the backup and brought to the newly restored database? And if so, is it possible to exclude this?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [RESTORE documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql) states:

> During a restore, most of the database options that are settable using
>   ALTER DATABASE are reset to the values in force at the time of the end
>   of backup.

So if the source database is in `RESTRICTED_USER`, the database will be set to that mode during the restore. You can, however, specify the `WITH RESTRICTED_USER` option during the restore to set the restored database to `RESTRICTED_USER` if the source database was backed up with a different option.

But there is no `RESTORE` option to specify `WITH MULTI_USER` so you'll need to execute `ALTER DATABASE` after the `RESTORE` to change the option.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Just a question out of curiousity. Do you know why it is possible to add `with restricted_user` but not `with multi_user`?

Comment: @wenzzzel, I suspect `RESTRICTED_USER` is implemented because it's the more common `RESTORE` use case of restoring from a backup taken in `MULTI_USER`. This permits validation of the database before toggling back to `MULTI_USER`. Consider submitting a [SQL Server product feedback suggestion](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server) to allow `MULTI_USER` or `SINGLE_USER` too.

Comment: That makes sense